# Виктор(?)тот ещё товарищ - нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Виктор(?)тот ещё товарищ.

Ставится ли тире в этом случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Устойчивый оборот "тот ещё товарищ"  относится к разговорной экспрессивной речи и  обычно выражает многозначительную оценку кого-чего-н. как плохого или сложного, затруднительного.

Оборот выступает в роли  именной части сказуемого, в этом случае между подлежащим и сказуемым ставится тире, а в  в устной речи делается пауза.

Для сравнения:Сапожки – что тебе зеркало! Сыновья  – один к одному. Заработок теперь у него – будь здоров.  Мы думали, что он спит, а он – ушки на макушке. А крыльцо – дай бог иному князю!

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ПОСЛЕ ДИСКУССИИ

Постановка тире между подлежащим и сказуемым регулируется большим количеством правил для множества конкретных примеров, но в то же время  все задачи по этой теме имеют одно общее решение: «есть пауза - ставим тире, нету паузы - не ставим». Во многих случаях  наличие тире/паузы определяется однозначно, но есть и парные варианты с авторским решением. 
Пожалуй, приведенный пример можно отнести к АВТОРСКОМУ, но при этом нужно понимать, какие оттенки СМЫСЛА соответствуют каждому случаю.

(1) Виктор – тот еще товарищ.  Тоническое ударение всегда падает на слово перед паузой, поэтому мы логически выделяем подлежащее.

(2) Виктор тот еще товарищ.   Здесь ударение падает на слово ТОТ, поэтому  логически выделяется сказуемое. Это разговорный стиль (а в разговорном стиле по официальным правилам допускается отсутствие тире).

Если добавить еще союз А, то «разговорность»  стиля становится более очевидной, и здесь уже пауза явно отсутствует: (3) А Виктор тот еще товарищ.